# Crystal Report Print Property Name

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an application in VB6 from which I print a report with Crystal Reports 4.0. 
For example, when I set a printer as the default printer pdf, when you open the dialog box to save the pdf file in the File name field I wrote "Seagate Crystal Reports - xxxxx.pdf." 
How do I set this code to the file name that comes by default? 
Which Crystal Report I have set to change the name of the file / print?

Thanks to all